# Configure VS Code for Microsoft C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

After following this tutorial
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc#_start-vs-code-from-the-developer-command-prompt

on the build task with any include header I get one error:

> main.cpp
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include\yvals.h(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
>   The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
>   Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I have the error in one computer, in another following the same tutorial it just works. I have tried installing the tools, installing vs community, everything.
I launch vscode using "code ." form vs2019 developer prompt (normal and as an administrator).

Is there any way I can fix this?

kind regards.

Comment: I have a possibly stupid question … If you're using MS build tools, and VS Code … Why not just use VS?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't install the Win10 SDK. But that's just a guess. It is not really possible to give you an definitive answer with the information youre giving us.

Comment: @ChrisMM I just want VSCode because I just want to do tiny console programs.

Comment: @Eric I did, including just one, several, the last one, and It did not work. By the way in two computers it just fails in one.